# Airflow installation error:"python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1"

Tags: python, airflow

I am trying to install airflow in Mac OS.
I have python 3.7.3 installed.
I did the following pip install apache-airflow==1.9.0

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/rh/4jxb065x3dl3vf1hr084qz100000gn/T/pip-install-oeuegs9g/apache-airflow/setup.py", line 102
        async = [
              ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/rh/4jxb065x3dl3vf1hr084qz100000gn/T/pip-install-oeuegs9g/apache-airflow/
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Starting with *Python 3.**7***, *async* is a "reserved" keyword used for coroutines (although [[Python]: PEP 492 -- Coroutines with async and await syntax](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0492) refers to *v3.5*)
- [[PyPI]: Apache-AirFlow 1.9.0](https://pypi.org/project/apache-airflow/1.9.0) on the other hand, is *Python 3.**4*** (a version that reached its *end-of-life*) compatible

To get past the error, simply use a newer *AirFlow* version (recommended using the latest), starting with *v1.**10***.4 (which is the 1<sup>st</sup> one compatible with *Python 3.7*).